Entity Framework connection with PostgreSQL through PostgreSQL
How to add a custom data source to Visual Studio 2019
I added
Npgsql Visual Studio Extension
Entity Framework 6
Npgsql
Entity Framework
to connect to a PostgreSQL database in my web forms application(4.8).
I have updated the app.config file accordingly.
<system.data>





</system.data>
Despite these steps, I am still unable to see PostgreSQL as an option while adding a new connection through the Entity Framework wizard.
enter image description here
Can someone please guide me step by step on how can I do this setup.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
